# What is the correct way of finding mass of a uniform flat plate?

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this mass of a flat plate question and I no matter what way I try, I cant solve it.
To find the mass, I tried doing

$f(x) = 1/sqrt(x^2+6x+13) $

$p\int_0^2 f(x) dx$ where density $p = 1$

and also

$\int_0^2\int_0^f p$ $dy$ $dx$

I tried doing those two since those are the two formulas I have been using and I have been getting them right on other questions. But in this particular one, I just cant. I would appreciate any help! thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}}\,dx$. Try completing the square: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+13}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+6x+9+4}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+3)^2+2^2}}$$ and using an appropriate substitution.